# have bot detect discord members rich presence

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm currently developing a private discord bot with discord.py that needs to detect the contents of a user's rich presence (ie the name of the game they're playing and the small description of what they're doing if the game provides it) and I can't find much explanation on how to use the rich presence api outside of the official discord.py docs. The end goal is to detect if they're playing x game with x description, but if anyone could explain the concept of it that would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's suppose we have a variable that is a instance of discord.Member named member. (can be gotten via `ctx.author` or by using `member: discord.Member` in your function parameters)

First we need to check if he is playing a game. for that we'll just loop through `member.activities` and see if the activity is a Game.

```py
game = None
for activity in member.activities:
    if isinstance(activity, discord.Game):
        game = activity
```

We looped here because a person may have multiple activities and only one of them is a Game.
Now we'll check if we found a game activity or not

```py
if game is None:
    return await ctx.send("Not playing any Games")
    # We have the return here because we don't want the command to go any further
```

Now we have a instance of [discord.Game](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Game) on our hands. We can use it to get some details such as

[game.name](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Game.name)
The name of the game
[game.details](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Activity.details)
The details/description of the game
[game.start](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Game.start)
When the user started playing the game
[game.large_image_url](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Activity.large_image_url)
The big image url
[game.small_image_url](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Activity.small_image_url)
The small image url
[game.large_image_text](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Activity.text)
The large image text that shows then you hover over the large image
[game.small_image_text](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Activity.small_image_text)
The small image text that shows then you hover over the small image

Note: Some of these attributes may be `None` if not provided by the game and for more attributes read the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#activity)